# Two onActivityResult conflict android

Tags: java, android, get, onactivityresult

I have two activities, `TakePictureActivity` and `ChoosePicActivity`, and they both lead to `PuzzleActivity`.

As you can see, 1st activity starts an intent to start the camera, allows you to take a picture and starts the `PuzzleActivity`.

The 2nd activity accesses to the gallery, allows you to choose a picture and starts the `PuzzleActivity`.

In the `PuzzleActivity` the method `createScaledBitmap` is called to generate a bitmap.

Here is `TakePictureActivity`:

```
public class TakePictureActivity extends Activity {

String mCurrentPhotoPath;
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
public static final int DIALOG_PICASA_ERROR_ID = 0;
private static String DEBUG_TAG1 = "TakePictureA";
private Bitmap bitmap;
public static Uri imageUri;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
    setContentView(R.layout.takepicture);
    dispatchTakePictureIntent();
}
//TODO createImageFile
   /* (non-Javadoc)
    * Creates a file for the picture with a collision-resistant name using date-time stamp.
    * Additionally, it saves the path to the picture in a member variable, mCurrentPhotoPath.
    */
   private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date(0));
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1,"Current photo Path" + mCurrentPhotoPath);
        galleryAddPic();
        return image;
    }
 //TODO dispatchTakePictureIntent
   /* (non-Javadoc)
    * Starts an intent for the camera application.
    */
   private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1,"try create iamge file");
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1,"error");
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1,"photo file not null");
                i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }
   private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

   @Override
   protected final void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent i) {
      //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, i);

      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1,"TakePicture onActivityResult ");
         switch (requestCode) {

         case REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO:
             imageUri = i.getData();
             Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1,"intent take pic: " + i);
             Intent i1 = new Intent(this, PuzzleActivity.class);
             startActivity(i1);
             break;
         } // end switch
      } // end if
   }
}
```

And here is ChoosePicActivity:

```
public class ChoosePicActivity extends Activity {

String mCurrentPhotoPath;
public static final int IMAGEREQUESTCODE = 8242008;
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
public static final int DIALOG_PICASA_ERROR_ID = 0;
private static String DEBUG_TAG1 = "ChoosePicA";
private Bitmap bitmap;
public static Uri imageUri;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
    selectImageFromGallery();
}


/* (non-Javadoc)
    * Will start an intent for external Gallery app.  
    * Image returned via onActivityResult().
    */   
private void selectImageFromGallery() {
      Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
            MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
      startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, IMAGEREQUESTCODE);
   }
 //TODO onActivityResult
   /* (non-Javadoc)
    * Run when Gallery app returns selected image.
    */
 @Override
   protected final void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent i) {
      //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, i);
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1,"ChoosePic onActivityResult ");
         switch (requestCode) {
         case IMAGEREQUESTCODE:
             imageUri = i.getData();
             Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1,"intent choose pic: " + i);
             Intent i1 = new Intent(this, PuzzleActivity.class);
             startActivity(i1);  
             break;
         } // end switch
      } // end if
   }

}
```

And here is the PuzzleActivity:

```
public final class PuzzleActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private Bitmap bitmap; // temporary holder for puzzle picture
public static Chronometer chrono;
static TextView tv1;
static EditText et1;
Button button;
private static Context mContext;



//TODO onCreate
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
setContentView(R.layout.board);
  mContext = this;
  tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movecount_display);

  if(DecidePicActivity.choosepic){
      try {
          bitmap = createScaledBitmap(ChoosePicActivity.imageUri);
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          showDialog(DIALOG_PICASA_ERROR_ID);
       } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          finish();
       } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
          showDialog(DIALOG_PICASA_ERROR_ID);
       }

       createGameBoard(getGridSize());
  }
  else if(DecidePicActivity.takepic){
      try {
          bitmap = createScaledBitmap(TakePictureActivity.imageUri);
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          showDialog(DIALOG_PICASA_ERROR_ID);
       } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          finish();
       } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
          showDialog(DIALOG_PICASA_ERROR_ID);
       }

       createGameBoard(getGridSize());
  }

  TileView.moveDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener());
  Button pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause_button);
  pauseButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

}

The issue is:

I get to `ChoosePicActivity`, I choose a pic from the gallery, start intent to go to `PuzzleActivity` and creates the scaled bitmap with the chosen picture.
All good until here.

then, `PuzzleActivity` gets finished and i get to `TakePictureActivity`, camera starts, i take a pic, start intent to go `PuzzleActivity` and THEN the scaled bitmap generated uses the image previously chosen in the `ChoosePicActivity`, leaving the recently taken picture behind, which is the picture that it should have been used to generate the scaled bitmap.

On the other hand, if `TakePictureActivity` is started without `ChoosePicActivity` previously started, the taken picture is used to generate the scaled bitmap, as expected.

I hope I explained myself enough good for you to understand my problem. Could somebody give some light?

I'm not sure if having 2 times the method `onActivityResult` is correct, or if there are different threads conflicting, or maybe the method `i.getdata()` is having trouble to get the proper `Intent` id... I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by `DecidePicActivity.choosepic` and `DecidePicActivity.takepic`.

Previously, `DecidePicActivity` activity was like this:

```
public class DecidePicActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
static boolean takepic = false;
static boolean choosepic = false;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
    setContentView(R.layout.decidepic);
    findViewById(R.id.take_pic_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.choose_pic_button).setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.take_pic_button:
            takepic = true;
            Intent i1 = new Intent(this, TakePictureActivity.class);
            startActivity(i1);
            break;
        case R.id.choose_pic_button:
            choosepic = true;
            Intent i2 = new Intent(this, ChoosePicActivity.class);
            startActivity(i2);
            break;
    }
}
```

}

`takepic` and `choosepic` they were not properly reinitialized.

Now `onClick` in `DecidePicActivity` activity is like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.take_pic_button:
            takepic = true;
            choosepic = false;
            Intent i1 = new Intent(this, TakePictureActivity.class);
            startActivity(i1);
            break;
        case R.id.choose_pic_button:
            choosepic = true;
            takepic = false;
            Intent i2 = new Intent(this, ChoosePicActivity.class);
            startActivity(i2);
            break;
    }
}
```

and problem solved!